# Doctrine not saving relation

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have this relation:

In `UserRole`

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand", inversedBy="managers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $brandManage;
```

In Brand

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserRole", mappedBy="brandManage")
     */
    private $managers;
```

in User

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserRole", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $role;
```

Now I am trying to assign a brand to `brandManage` in `UserRole` but the database is not updated; the relation is always Null even that the entity is correctly updated before saving (checked with dump)

For the purpose of the question I used three methods to save as you can see below; none of them work ! I also inserted a `die;` after with same results

```
$userRole->setBrandManage($brand);
$userRoleRepository->save($userRole);

$user->setRole($userRole);
$userRepository->save($user);

$this->em->persist($userRole);
$this->em->persist($user);
$this->em->flush();
```

Now I noticed that if I create a new `UserRole` the relation is correctly saved but never if I am updating an existing `UserRole`.

So I tried to always create a new one but for some reason doctrine is not saving the new `UserRole` because it says that a `UserRole` with same User Id already exists in the DataBase but it is NOT. I have to save a second time for the new `UserRole` to be created...

EDIT:
If I do the following sequence it works but that makes no sense to have it so complicated.... Why can't I just save the role ?
This workaround is effectively creating a new `UserRole` by removing it before saving it again... So back to the original problem

```
$userRole->setBrandManage($brand);
$userRoleRepository->save($userRole);
                    
$user->setRole($userRole);
$userRepository->save($user);

$this->em->remove($user->getRole());
$this->em->flush();

$this->em->persist($userRole);
$this->em->persist($user);
$this->em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

The save function already persist in database. You will chose beteween sava or persist function.

```
$userRole->setBrandManage($brand);
$user->setRole($userRole);
// Note if you set cascade persist from user to role, you can omit that line
$this->em->persist($userRole); 
$this->em->persist($user);
$this->em->flush();
```